# How to test if a macro identifier is defined without using #ifdef?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, metaprogramming, variadic-macros, p99

Does anyone know how to, or if it's even possible to, create a variadic macro that expands to 0 if it's argument is not a defined macro, but expands to 1 if it's argument is a defined macro?  (I'm using c99.)

```
#define BOB
#define SUE 45
#define IS_DEFINED(...) ???
IS_DEFINED(JOE)  <---- expands to 0
IS_DEFINED(BOB)  <---- expands to 1 (it's okay if this one doesn't work)
IS_DEFINED(SUE)  <---- expands to 1
```

**EDIT:** I specifically don't want any `#if`-related solutions... it needs to be a variadic macro (if that's possible) so I can do things like this:

```
#define CAT_(x, y) x ## y
#define CAT(x, y) CAT_(x, y)
#define CLEANUP0(...) ABC  <--- treats __VA_ARGS__ one way
#define CLEANUP1(...) XYZ  <--- treats __VA_ARGS__ a different way
#define CLEANUP(...) CAT(CLEANUP, IS_DEFINED(DEFAULT))(__VA_ARGS__)
```

Where `ABC` & `XYZ` are placeholders for other expansions that treat `__VA_ARGS__` very differently.

Comment: `#if defined(JOE)`?

Comment: I mean I don't get why, but if you want to use a variadic macro instead of `#ifdef` or `#if defined()` you could use a more powerful preprocessor like m4 to create macros that can have `#ifdef` in them perhaps. Seems a bit too overkill though. Is there any specific reason you need to do this, so maybe it would be easier to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether a macro is defined with `defined()`, however this only works in the same circumstances where an `#ifdef` works (as far as I'm aware). I don't think this is possible but I might be mistaken.

Edit:

I don't know if this helps with what you want because the result will not be a constant expression. However if you want you could define the following macros:

```c
#define _IS_DEFINED(...) (!!*#__VA_ARGS__)
#define IS_DEFINED(...) _IS_DEFINED(__VA_ARGS__)
#define BOB
```

if we now evaluate this we will get

```c
int main() {
        printf("%d\n", IS_DEFINED(BOB));
}
```

which will give us

```
0
```

This is because `IS_DEFINED(BOB)` expands to `(!!*"")`. In this case `""` is just a pointer to some `NUL` byte in your .data section and dereferencing it will yield 0. But again, this is not a constant expression and as such the value is only avaliable to further usage in C and not the preprocessor. It also doesn't evaluate the second possibility as you wanted (like the example shows).

Comment: This is a good trick @Leander (one I know) but unfortunately I need the `0` or `1` at precompilation time.

Comment: @DavidRanieri No, I needed a logical identity in order to get a 1 for all possible char values except `NUL`. If you just care about the logical value you could also just leave the negations out.